# something/some things to be desired

Tags: noun-phrases

I know the phrase "leaves a lot to be desired" is used frequently in today's English.

But how should we rephrase it when we want to be a little more conservative?:

> it leaves something to be desired

Or

> it leaves some things to be desired

And are (either of) these a good way to say what I'm hoping to?

Comment: The first sentence is found on thefreedictionary.com. I have never seen or heard the second one before, but the first one is definitely correct. I am not sure if it differs much in intensity from the construction with *a lot*. According to the mentioned dictionary, they are synonymous.

Answer (score 1):

When you say that ***something leaves a lot to be desired***, you are saying that it is 
not as good as it could be, inadequate.

Examples:

The food in that restaurant left a lot to be desired.

leave a lot to be desired **~** ***[leaves something to be desired](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=pSNLCAAAQBAJ&pg=PT73&dq=%22leaves%20a%20lot%20to%20be%20desired%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCIQ6AEwA2oVChMIm63R4r-UxgIVx3y8Ch32ZAAd#v=onepage&q=%22leaves%20a%20lot%20to%20be%20desired%22&f=false).***